# Why java nio2 can`t listen a udp port?

Tags: java, udp, nio2

Why "java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocket" always listen tcp port? If it could, how can I use it? Which classes are they?

Comment: a simple search for java udp will result in `DatagramSocket`

Answer (score 3):

They added it and then they removed it in ealier developement stage for jdk 7.

See this: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6993126

Answer (score 0):

UDP is done with the [DatagramSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html). The nio functionality can be achieved by [getting the associated channel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#getChannel--).

Comment: I might be wrong, but Channels / Selectors are not NIO.2, they belong to the old NIO pattern.

Comment: @vbence, yes - nio.2 is primarily focused on new ways to work with the file system. The question is really about nio, not nio.2.

Answer (score 0):

Because, as the Javadoc says, `AsynchronousSocketChannel` is 'an asynchronous channel for stream-oriented connecting sockets', i.e. TCP, and they didn't provide an `AsynchronousDatagramChannel` yet.

Comment: But, Why they didn't provide an AsynchronousDatagramChannel yet?